# emacs mouse shift-select from cursor point

Tags: select, emacs, mouse

can anyone point me in the right direction to globally define the activation of shift select with the left mouse button? 
I want to be able to select between the cursor point and the selected area... 
It is possible to drag-select only, and it is possible to shift-select via keyboard only.

This unfortunately doesn't work (in ~/.emacs):

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'shift-selection)
```

Machine: Win7, Emacs-Version: 25.1.1 (i686-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(define-key global-map (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'mouse-save-then-kill)`

https://superuser.com/questions/521223/shift-click-to-extend-marked-region